# find out current position in OSMdroid

Tags: android, osmdroid

I want to find map of my current position and update it when i move via showing a icon in OSMdroid.I find no problem when give specific location latitude and longitude and drawing icon but there are two errors when i give current location latitude and longitude.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mResourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.main);        
    mMapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mMapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);        
    mapController = this.mMapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(15);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    String provider = mLocMgr.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = mLocMgr.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    GeoPoint mypoint = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()); // centre map here
    GeoPoint mypointicon = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude()+1000, location.getLongitude()+1000); // icon goes here
    mapController.setCenter(mypoint);            
    mLocMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 100,
            this);        
    ArrayList<OverlayItem> items=new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    items.add(new OverlayItem("Here", "Sample Description", mypointicon));
    this.mMyLocationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(items,
            new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index,
                        final OverlayItem item) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            MapOverLayGiveActivity.this,
                            "Item '" + item.mTitle, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true; // We 'handled' this event.
                }
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index,
                        final OverlayItem item) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            MapOverLayGiveActivity.this, 
                            "Item '" + item.mTitle ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }
            }, mResourceProxy);
    this.mMapView.getOverlays().add(this.mMyLocationOverlay);
    mMapView.invalidate();        
}
```

Error:
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.RunTimeException

What's wrong in my code and how can i do that? thanks...

Comment: I wrote an answer on this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575285/determine-user-location-on-osm-maps/10585267#10585267). Please see if it's ok for you.

Comment: actually i don't want to specify latitude and longitude(MAP_DEFAULT_LATITUDE = 44.445883 MAP_DEFAULT_LONGITUDE = 26.040963) but OSMdroid will take current position's latitude and longitude.how can i do it?

Answer (score 6):

To follow location changes, implement LocationListener as below:

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        currentLocation = new GeoPoint(location);
        displayMyCurrentLocationOverlay();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```

Inside onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();        
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if( location != null ) {
        currentLocation = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    }
}
```

and displayMyCurrentLocationOverlay method:

```
private void displayMyCurrentLocationOverlay() {
    if( currentLocation != null) {
        if( currentLocationOverlay == null ) {
            currentLocationOverlay = new ArrayItemizedOverlay(myLocationMarker);
            myCurrentLocationOverlayItem = new OverlayItem(currentLocation, "My Location", "My Location!");
            currentLocationOverlay.addItem(myCurrentLocationOverlayItem);
            mapView.getOverlays().add(currentLocationOverlay);              
        } else {
            myCurrentLocationOverlayItem.setPoint(currentLocation);
            currentLocationOverlay.requestRedraw();
        }
        mapView.getController().setCenter(currentLocation);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use this.myLocationOverlay - and because of that the osmDroid draw the current location - but for update the location you must use a location listener. Also, you must remove previous overlay from the map using `mapView.getOverlays.clear()` function

Well, let's say that you don't have acces to internet or GPS. In my opinion is safe to have a default point on the map.
In this code I check for a valid location. If is null, then I use DEFAULT values. 
In my application I have no problems. I also draw a navigation path on the map, even if my location is changed.

```
{
    Location location = null;

            for (String provider : locationManager.getProviders(true))
            {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                if (location != null)
                {
                    //location.setLatitude(MAP_DEFAULT_LATITUDE);
                    //location.setLongitude(MAP_DEFAULT_LONGITUDE);
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, mUpdateHandler);
                    break;
                }
            }

            //add car position
            if (location == null)
            {
                location = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                location.setLatitude(MAP_DEFAULT_LATITUDE);
                location.setLongitude(MAP_DEFAULT_LONGITUDE);
                updateCarPosition(new GeoPoint(location));
            }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you test on Emulator then remember use DDMS to set your current lat & long. if you don't, the getLastKnownLocation will return null